# remove all consecutive repeating given character in a string using PHP

Tags: php

How can I remove all consecutive repeating letter "p" from a string.

For instance, "happy purple kitten said pppplease" will become 'hapy purple kitten said please"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could accomplish this with a regular expression:

```
/pp+/
```

You can use PHP's [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to do the actual replacement:

```
$str = preg_replace('/pp+/', 'p', $str);
```

This effectively says to take any `p` followed by "one or more `p`'s" and replace them with a single `p`.

[**Codepad example.**](http://codepad.org/l551XB2u)

Comment: Thanks newfuniturey.  Probably will.  I had thought something like `string_replace('pp','p',"happy purple kitten said pppplease")` would work, but no.

Comment: @user1032531 Your example, `preg_replace('pp'...` will only match an exact case where there are two `p`'s; it would be the same as `str_replace('pp', 'p', $str)`. If you use `pp+`, that will match "two or more"

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at using preg_replace (http://php.net/preg_replace)?

Here is an example for you to play with:

```
<?php
$str = "happy purple kitten said pppplease";

$result = preg_replace('/pp+/', 'p', $str);

var_dump($str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace( '/pp+/','p', $mystring );
```

Answer (score 1):

This pattern replaces all repeated characters with one:

```
<?php
$string = "happy purple kitten said pppplease";
echo preg_replace("/([a-z])(\\1+)/i", '\\1', $string);//hapy purple kiten said please

//for your case
echo preg_replace("/([p])(\\1+)/i", '\\1', $string);//hapy purple kitten said please
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using str_replace using a loop to repeat until all of the 'pp' strings are replaced by 'p', like so:

```
while( strpos($str, 'pp') !== FALSE ) {
  $str=str_replace('pp', 'p', $str);
}
```

Comment: Never seen the approach above, is there any advantage over this instead of using preg_replace?

Comment: I suppose it's mostly a matter of different styles of coding.  If someone is not so familiar with regular expressions, then this approach might be easier to understand, although your approach using preg_replace may run faster.